# how can i change the connection string from an IP to a server name in Weblogic 12c?

Tags: hibernate, weblogic12c

I want to change the connection string from an IP to a server name (e.g., serverA) in weblogic 12c. how should i approach that?

```
jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@19.19.19.19:1521:dbname
jdbc.username=username
jdbc.password=password
```

Comment: you can give the hostname instead of ipaddress, what is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently in the process of setting up an Oracle SOA Server myself.

In order to acheieve that; you will have to start the Weblogic configuration wizard, also known as the domain configuration wizard; you can find it at

`$ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/common/bin/config`

then through the managed servers change the ip into the hostname

[image: Managed Servers]

and I recommend that you do the same for the node manager

[image: Node Manager]